# Compare Excel value to SQL table If statements.

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vba, excel

Is there a way I can use VBA to search a SQL table and return a Yes/No result if a cell in excel contains the same data found in a SQL table??

I have customer records in an Excel sheet where I need to compare the record id (A1) I need to compare cell by cell to the 'Client' table if there is a match, if so... I need some sort of output from sql if the value exists or not.

Example:
 If Cell.A1 is = SQLTableA 
then 'yes'
else 
'no'

I feel like I am close, but cant get the right output from sql.

```
enter code here
Option Explicit
Dim cell As Range
Dim CustRow As Range

Const SQLConStr As String = "Driver={SQL Server} ;Server=<svrname>;Database=CustData; UID=user; PWD=<pass>"

Sub connectTODB()

Dim CustDataConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim CustDataCMD As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset


Set CustDataConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set CustDataCMD = New ADODB.Command
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

CustDataConn.ConnectionString = SQLConStr
CustDataConn.Open
CustDataCMD.ActiveConnection = CustDataConn


Dim CustValue As String
CustValue = "ACP"


Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [CustData].[dbo].[CustomerData] WHERE (CustomerData.Client='" & CustValue & "')"



With rs
.ActiveConnection = CustDataConn
'open strsql

'.Open "IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [CustData].[dbo].[CustomerData] WHERE CustomerData.Client = 'ACA') Print 'Yes' Else Print 'No'" '(notworking)
'.Open "IF EXISTS(SELECT Client FROM CustData.dbo.CustomerData WHERE  CustomerData.Client = 'hdh') Print 'Yes' Else Print 'No'" '(notworking)
.Open "IF EXISTS(SELECT Client FROM CustData.dbo.CustomerData WHERE  CustomerData.Client = 'hdh')"

Workbooks("<file>.xlsm").Worksheets("CustOutput").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

.Close
End With

CustDataConn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set CustDataConn = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: yes you can do that. I would shoot for a named cell in Excel, and a stored proc call

Comment: I only wrote one of these [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33489270). Due to the wild review it got, I am loathe to do another.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `IF EXISTS(SELECT`? If you're just wanting one value copied into one cell - you don't need `copyfromrecordset`. Just get your connection string right, and the query working with the specific field you want back. Then assign `rs!YourFieldName` to the cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can someone check my understanding here...

This will open the connection and send the string, then filter my value, after the filter the .BOF will return as false, I change the answer to a "yes/no" result and output that to a cell....

I have not used the BOF (EOF) values before and the description from Microsoft is even harder to understand...  but..

If BOF = True (then the value does not exist > change to "No")

If BOF = False (then the value does exist > change to "Yes")

so..

```
enter code here

With rs

.ActiveConnection = CustDataConn
.Open strSQL
.Filter = "Client = 'ABC'"
Workbooks("file.xlsm").Worksheets("CustOutput").Range("A2") = IIf(.BOF, "No", "Yes")
.Close

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ADODB.Recordset.Filter` property to return just the matching records.  If there are no matching records then `ADODB.Recordset.BOF` will return true.

```
With rs
    .ActiveConnection = CustDataConn
    .Open strSQL

    .Filter = "CustomerData.Client = 'ACA'"
    Debug.Print IIf(.BOF, "No", "Yes")

    .Filter = "CustomerData.Client = 'hdh'"
    Debug.Print IIf(.BOF, "No", "Yes")

    'Clear Filter
    .Filter = ""

    Workbooks("<file>.xlsm").Worksheets("CustOutput").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    .Close
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas Inzina .

Comment: I was unable to use the provided answer. different runtime errors and the output results were wrong. (I am new to asking questions, I am having a hard time replying with code...)